# Views Not Creating in Custom Routes in Laravel + Vue.Js

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am Using Laravel 5.5 and Vue.js 2.0 
When i open `example.com` and click on **Display Items** then this url triggered
  `example.com/items`
and here are results 
[image: Views Not Creating in Custom Routes in Laravel + Vue.Js]

and When i open directly this url `example.com/items` it shows me only json response that i am getting from Laravel without creating any view in html (Vue.js).
See Below: 
[image: Views Not Creating in Custom Routes in Laravel + Vue.Js]

How Can I Get Exact Results in Browser by Visiting Direct Urls like `example.com/items` without visiting `example.com` first.

 
**Updated**
Here is My Vue routes.js File

```
import Example from './components/ExampleComponent.vue'
import CreateItem from './components/CreateItem.vue'
import DisplayItem from './components/DisplayItem.vue'
import EditItem from './components/EditItem.vue'

export const routes = [
    { name: 'Example', path: '/', component: Example },
    { name: 'CreateItem', path: '/items/create', component: CreateItem },
    { name: 'DisplayItem', path: '/items', component: DisplayItem },
    { name: 'EditItem', path: '/items/:id/edit', component: EditItem }
];
```

Getting Response From Laravel Like This

```
$items = Items::all();
//        dd($items);
        return response()->json($items);
```

DisplayItems.vue File Vue.js Code

```
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{ items: [] }
        },
        created: function()
        {
            this.fetchItems();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchItems()
            {
                this.axios.get('/items').
                    then(response => {
                        this.items = response.data;
                    });
            },
            deleteItem(id)
            {
                let uri = '/items/'+id;
                this.items.splice(id, 1);
                this.axios.delete(uri);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[BEHAVIOUR]** 
`laravel` have it's own server with routes.
When you trying to refresh custom `Vue.js` route, it shows overrides `Vue.js` routes with `laravel` route and shows you only **JSON** response. 
**[SOLUTION]** 
You should create `Vue.js` application and Use `laravel-echo` or `laravel broadcasting` and use `laravel` api.
Now make each request from Vue to direct API and Get Response.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is returning a `JsonResponse` from the route `/items`, hence why you see JSON in the browser. Vue binds the JSON to dom elements.

You would need to modify the route to `/items` so that it returns JSON if `$request->wantsJson()` and a regular Response if non ajax.

Comment: Wait Let Me Show you My Vue Routes File

Comment: Please Check Now Question Again File Source Code as well

Comment: Vue routes are for client side routing, they are not making the api request, axios is. You must have a routes.php file or similar, yes? In it is `Route::get('items', 'ItemController')`? Like I said, you need to modify the server side function to return the view response and items data when accessing with a browser.

Comment: How can i add a server side function?
My Controller Code is Already Added Above.
How can i re-render vue? Please Write a simple example here

Comment: Do you have an ItemController in `app/Http/Controllers`?

Comment: Yes I have and it is working fine when i visit `example.com` first then click on router-link `/items` and all Dom elements working great in this case.
Just having issue when i open direct url in browser like `example.com/items`, in this case it return a json only

Comment: I should probably back up and ask is this an SPA?